# How can I force js to append + to front of positive number?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the follow angular filter

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function(angular) {

    function positiveFormatter() {
        return function (input) {
            if (input > 0) {
                return '+' + input;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('wfFilters').filter('positiveFormatter', positiveFormatter);
});
```

If the number is positive, it should add the + in front of it, but it does not.

If I make it

```
return '+ ' + input;
```

it does put the + and space in front.

How can I force it to put the + in from of a positive number?

EDIT

I am guessing it has something to do with the + directly. If I change the + to - or any letter, it returns what it should return.

If I change it to

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function(angular) {

    function positiveFormatter() {
        return function (input) {
            if (input > 0) {
                return '+6';
            } else {
                return '-1';
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('wfFilters').filter('positiveFormatter', positiveFormatter);
});
```

I still get a 6 without the + but will get -1.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the `return '+' input` line to make sure that 1. the filter is being used and 2. the `input` variable is of the type you expect?

Comment: I have done that and the filter is being used and the variable is 6 . Good thoughts

Answer (score 0):

In all likeliness the `input` is a string.

Try:

```
define(['angular'], function(angular) {

    function positiveFormatter() {
        return function (input) {
            input = +input;
            if (input > 0) {
                return '+' + input;
            } else {
                return input;
            }
        };
    }

    angular.module('wfFilters').filter('positiveFormatter', positiveFormatter);
});
```

Comment: It does not matter if input is a string; `>` operator changes it to number (the same magic as is behind unary `+`).

Comment: Are you sure that is a string rather than some fancy angular type?

Comment: @Joe I made some edits to the question to show some things I have attempted with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it had nothing to do with the js method. The html that was calling it was then calling a setDecimal js method that was removing the +.